# Spring Boot gives CORS error when PathVariable is encoded due to special characters

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I want to create an endpoint in Spring Boot which gives me the details of an Entity. The controller for the moment looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.semdetect.server.entities.models.Entity;
import com.semdetect.server.entities.services.EntityService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/entity")
public class EntityController {
    private final EntityService entityService;

    @Autowired
    public EntityController(EntityService entityService) {
        this.entityService = entityService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{iri}")
    public Entity getEntityByIri(@PathVariable String iri) {
        System.out.println("In controller: " + iri);
        return this.entityService.getEntityByIri(iri);
    }
}
```

I am using the @PathVarible annotation to get the ID of the Entity from the URI.

My CORS config looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I do a request like this:

GET http://localhost:8080/api/entity/12345869

It enters the controller and console logs the ID: `12345869`.

Everything fine until now... but my database is an RDF database, so my **IDs are URIs** and look like this:

<http://www.semanticweb.org/blah/ontologies/2022/6/blah#12345869>

So my request will actually look like this, containing special characters:

GET http://localhost:8080/api/entity/<http://www.semanticweb.org/blah/ontologies/2022/6/blah#12345869>

Because of the special characters I am using the `encodeURIComponent` from JavaScript to encode the path variable (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

`http://localhost:8080/api/entity/${encodeURIComponent("\<http://www.semanticweb.org/blah/ontologies/2022/6/blah#12345869\>")}`

Which will turn the request into this:

[image]

When I do this request with the path variable encoded... Spring Boot returns CORS error, although with normal IDs it works.

I don't know how to resolve this issue, is there any way I can use a string like <http://www.semanticweb.org/blah/ontologies/2022/6/blah#12345869> as a path variable?

EDIT (AS REUQESTED IN THE COMMENTS):

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sem-detect</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>rdf4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-client</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-repository-sparql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am using JDK 18.

Comment: are you using spring security?

Comment: Nope, the project is a poc in a very incipient phase, so not yet.

Comment: I think you should provide jdk version, pom.xml etc

Comment: You can use Base64 encoding

Comment: Does your RDF database allows CORS request, if not enable them first, also you can use URldecode to decode encoded URI

Comment: It allows CORS... my issue it has nothing to do with the DB config... the DB interogtion from Spring Boot has no idea about the request. I can totally take out the DB service from the controller and the issue still persists. The issue is related to path variables... if I move the ID in the query string the ecncode/decode process works perfectly. The problem is when I am trying to use the ID in the path variable.

Comment: Unfortunately no... for the moment I moved temporary the URI in the query variable... so I don't block development...